# Most efficient/fastest way to set content on a bunch of divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently updating the content of alot of divs using:

https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/ctpuaw5v/

```
for (var i = 0; i < 400; i++)
{
   document.getElementById('box' + i).innerHTML = 'a'; // each element can have a different value, a is arbitrary
}
```

(400 is arbitrary, it could be alot more)

I'm wondering as far as browser reflow, would it do a reflow on each innerHTML set, and if so, maybe there's a way for me to update all divs at once with only one reflow (or even NO reflow) for performance reasons, or maybe use something faster than innerHTML.

Comment: you can detach the container, set all the innerHTMLs in a loop, then re-attach for only one major reflow instead of 400 little ones. which one is better depends on lots of things. fragments are good too. pre-sizing content sub-containers helps a lot as well.

Comment: @dandavis interesting, please show example

Comment: @foreyez http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/

Comment: code that i post that runs a certain way today could run differently in 6 weeks...

Comment: This kind of performance optimisation usually has very different results on different hosts (even versions of hosts), so develop a bunch of tests and test widely.

Comment: In your current example setting the innerHTML is fairly fast, because the divs have a fixed size (no reflow needed). Are the actual elements also of a fixed size?

Comment: Me.Name yes, they're fixed size. but it seems that it's still doing some expensive calculation when I set them.

Answer (score 0):

If you can replace 400 calls of `elem.innerHTML = ...;` by single call of 
`container.innerHTML = cummulativeHtml;` it will be faster - only one DOM mutation transaction instead of 400.

Comment: Check how you generate that `cummulativeHtml` - I am pretty sure problem is there.

Comment: i've recently noticed that in chrome at least, it's _very_ cheap to call `.innerHTML=` if the new content matches the old... almost like a `shouldComponentUpdate()`-like routine is built into the DOM now...

Comment: @dandavis, that's right. but my content almost always does not match the old. I'm also doing this on animation of the container, so I need this to be as fast as possible.

Comment: well it's a very complex and ever-changing process going on under the hood. sync DOM updates in a loop like that are sure to be internally bundled into one fell swoop... you should also put your loop inside a requestAnimationFrame callback to give the browser more hints about intentions.

Comment: "*…it will be faster…*" not necessarily, it depends very much on the changes involved and how the layout and rendering engines work.

Comment: @RobG 1) calling native method from script cost something and 2) for each `insertHtml` browser shall a) instantiate/prepare/setup HTML parser  and b) ensure that DOM is in consistent state after each call.

Comment: @c-smile— *innerHTML* is a property, not a method. While you might guess about the tasks to be performed, you can't know what's actually happening without detailed knowledge of exactly how several browsers **actually** work.

Comment: I do know how HTML/CSS/Script combination works as I am an author of one of them - http://sciter.com

Answer (score -3):

If you use jquery you can just do something like:

```
$('.box').html('whatever');
```

Comment: You answer should explain how it's faster.